# Updating Android Project to Gradle 7 leads to "layout.xml: Error: is not annotated as @Input"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When updating my Android Apps with Android Studio from Gradle 6.7.1 to Gradle 7.0.2 the projects suddenly have build errors.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libMyAndroidModule:packageDebugResources'.
<path>/src/main/res/layout/blue_progress_background.xml: Error: is not annotated as @Input
```

Unfortunately I can't find anything about this build error that would usually be related to a Gradle Task not being correctly annotated, yet in this case I can't change anything with the Gradle Task "packageDebugResources" and it's unusual that the xml would be actually responsible for causing this.

blue_progress_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>

            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="com.company.subscriptionuikit.viewmodel.SubscribeViewModel" />

        </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/blue_background_framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color_main"
        tools:context=".activity.SubscribeActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/split_linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/outer_spacing_blue_linearlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/blue_first_spacing_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/processing_text_linearlayout"
                    android:layout_width="260dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/almost_done_textview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/almost_done"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_main_colored"
                        android:textSize="22sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/processing_your_upgrade_textview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/we_are_processing_your_upgrade_and_updating_your_subscription_this_may_take_a_couple_of_seconds"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_main_colored"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/blue_second_spacing_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-14dp"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/tint_color_primary"
                android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/outer_spacing_white_linearlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/backgroundPrimaryTheme"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/white_first_spacing_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/continue_using_app_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="onClickContinueUsingApp"
                    android:text="Continue using App"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/selector_state_tint_blue"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/white_second_spacing_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Can you post your `blue_progress_background.xml` file?

Comment: Did you update all the dependencies as well? Can you poste your app-level `build.gradle`.

Comment: I posted the xml file. The hint with updating all the dependencies I will try. The app-level build.gradle is pretty big, I'll see if I can post this too though.

Comment: Do you really need databinding in this xml file? I can't really see where you use the viewModel at all. I would try to remove it and try to build again.

Comment: You're right, in this file I don't need the databinding. Removing it doesn't change anything unfortunately though.

Comment: Did you ever find out the cause of this error?

Comment: I didn't. I quit working on the code base. I've heard that it might have been fixed, but I'm also waiting for someone to provide an answer, so I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: I am getting this error when I create an activity xml file in module libraries.

Comment: i found this error at Azure DevOps, after 2 days work. the problem is in the directory name, because the letters in the directory name should be small but large. that's the problem i found. and it's fixed.

Comment: I can confirm on my side you're right @Jalalkun (after having the same issue) i was able to fix it by changing the case the directory name of one of my module.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because AGP7 uses very strict checksums, just make sure that the project name in the settings.gradle is exactly the same as the project name in the project path